# What is exactly difference between $(\partial f)/\partial x$ and $df/ dx$ , Where f=f(x,y,z)?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

I have a problem about meaning partial derivative.Question is following;

What are the meaning difference between $(\partial f)/\partial x$ and $df/ dx$ , Where $f=f(x, y, z)$ ?

For example , $f$ is area of a triangle respect to $x$, $y$, $z$  and we want to find rate of change area respect to $z$. Should we use $(\partial f)/\partial z$ or $df/ dz$ ?

Comment: $df$ is the total derivative wrt to all variables. Each $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  }$ is wrt to each variable.

Comment: but when we calculate the derivatives , they become equal ?

Comment: you need to check the definition of the total derivative first

Comment: The way this question is stated now, I don't think it is related to the total derivative.  The notation $(\partial f)/\partial x$ (with those parentheses) is never used, but $\partial f/\partial x$ is standard notation for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.  If $f$ is a function of $x,y,z$, then I think the notation $df/dx$ is not used.  However, if $f$ is a function of a single variable $x$, then $df/dx$ is the derivative of $f$.

Comment: remember $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$  is the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t.  $x$ assuming all other variables ($y$ & $z$) as constants. While $\frac{df}{dx}$ is the exact derivative  of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ assuming all other variables ($y$ & $z$) as function of $x$

Comment: @littleO But there is a approximation formula for both $ \partial f and df $

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot for this instruction answer the example shoud be df/dx if we put here a constraint right?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot got it , thanks.

Comment: In the example you gave in the question, you wanted the rate of change of area with respect to $z$.  So are you now saying the answer would be $df/dx$?  Why would that be the case?

Comment: @littleO I don't understand , what do you mean by "Why would that be the case ?"

Comment: If you want the rate of change of the area with respect to $z$, why would the answer be $df/dx$?  Why not $\partial f/\partial z$? @HarishChandraRajpoot

Comment: Of course answer should be df/dz .I just did a typo.

Comment: Ah, two people made the same typo so I wasn't sure.  It's not standard to use the notation $df/dz$ in this situation where $f$ is a function of several variables.  Rather, the notation $\partial f/ \partial z$ should be used.

Comment: @littleO: The rate of change of area w.r.t. $z$ should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ while the rate of change of area w.r.t. $x$ should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both notations are used to denote the derivative, although the one with $\partial$ is more common (and the one with a roman $d$ is almost always reserved either for a function of a single variable, or for situations like
$$
f(s, t) = s^2 + t^3\\
z = f(x, x^2)
$$
Now one speaks of $\frac{dz}{dx}$, and sometimes folks will simply write something like
$$
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^3\\
z = f(x, x^2)
$$
and then informally call $z$ by the name $f$ and write $df/dx$ (alas). I find this completely baffling, but friends who work in Physics do this all the time.

Sadly, the fact is that these things are ambiguous. For instance, if
$$
f(x, y, z) = x + \sin z
$$
and 
$$
g(x, y, z) = f(y, x, z)
$$
then the application of the chain rule to compute 
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$
would say that it's 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$
where the first two partials of $f$ are almost meaningless. There's a lot to be said for instead using
$$
D_1 f
$$
to denote the derivative of $f$ with respect to its first argument, so that 
if 
$$
f(x, y, z) = x + \sin z \\
g(z, y, x) = z + \sin x
$$
then (since $g$ and $f$ are the same function) we have
$$
D_1 f (3, 2) = D_1 g(3, 2)
$$
while in the Leibniz notation, we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}
$$
and vice-versa.

The downside is that the chain rule in the "partials" form is so very easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

The notation depends on the number of variables of a function. If the function has only one variable then you write

$\frac{dy}{dx}$

for the first derivative w.r.t. $x$.

If the function has more than one variable then you write

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

for the first (partial) derivative w.r.t. $x$.